# How to view the signing certificate of outlook before sending email using C# addin

Tags: .net, outlook

using the ribbon xml addin one can send signed email by enabling sign button using schema name as

string PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003";

Here before sending the email, the user should be able to view the signing certificate that is installed for digital signature.

Can anyone suggest method to retrieve the signing certificate programmatically using ribbon xml addin.